# The best way to bind a ajax call to Html.CheckBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, checkbox

I have a list of items and each item has a Html.CheckBox. What is the best way to bind a ajax call to that checkbox. Is there a a sexy way "like" Ajax.ActionLink or just use jQuery for this?

So my question is: is there a MVC ajax way of doing this or do I just do this with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use jQuery AJAX - it is the 'sexy' way because it's also the simplest.

The MVC way to do this is just that - MVC is all about simple clean HTML that's easy to write javascript for, rather than tons of plug-in server-side options that produce horrible HTML like WebForms.

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to be sure :)